# PNG + CSS3 Transition + Blur causing unexpected effects

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

Let me explain the situation.

I've a div that contains 5 images. each image is positioned absolute in the div in 5 'slots'.

My javascript scroll this images by changing class 'slot-0' ... 'slot-4', each class contains top/left positioning for elements.

And each image is set to have CSS transition 1s and Blur filter, except the central image that does not blur.

As long the movement ocours, in some browsers a unexpected effect occours: a 'inner shadow' like effect occours in transparent PNG borders.

HTML:

```
<div id="showcase-container" class="">
   <img src="0.png" class="slot-0">
   <img src="1.png" class="slot-1">
   <img src="2.png" class="slot-2">
   <img src="3.png" class="slot-3">
   <img src="4.png" class="slot-4">
</div>
```

LESS:

```
// Mixins
.blur (@radius: 3px) {
    filter: blur(@radius); 
    -webkit-filter: blur(@radius); 
    -moz-filter: blur(@radius);
    -o-filter: blur(@radius);
    -ms-filter: blur(@radius);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='@radius');
}
#showcase-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    .item {
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        &.slot-0 {
            width: 30%;
            top: 29%;
            left: -40%;
            .blur()
        }
        &.slot-1 {
            width: 25%;
            top: 27%;
            left: -10%;
            .blur();
        }
        &.slot-2 {
            width: 20%;
            top: 21%;
            left: 40%;
        }
        &.slot-3 {
            width: 13%;
            top: 23%;
            left: 80%;
            .blur(3px);
        }
        &.slot-4 {
            width: 7%;
            top: 18%;
            left: 120%;
            .blur();
        }
        &.animate {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

When I 'move' the image elements by changing it slot class for the next one
(slot-0 to slot-1, slot1 to slot2, ...), the problem occours.

[image: Unexpected results]

And this unexpected result just occours in images while it have blur filter.

I've removed this error in some MAC safari using

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
```

But not in some windows machines. (My development machine does not have erros, but my personal pc and my client pc does.)

Any help about this?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: what browsers were the windows machines using? IE?

Comment: codepen: http://codepen.io/agconti/pen/ckzJn

Comment: did u try it by using the prefixes for these properties
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);  ?

Comment: Could you please take the time and make a JSFiddle out of this, then we can see your problem and actually help you solve it. Hard to replicate this exactly how you describe it.